# Does user always pays as per the max instance limit of an Azure App Service plan irrespective of the actual instances deployed?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

As per my understanding one can add many web applications on one Azure App Service plan. App Service plan SKU determines how many web application instance (new or existing) I could run on App Service plan.

**Does this means users always pay as per the max scale out instance capacity for an Azure App Service Plan irrespective of the number of instances deployed in App Service plan?**

E.g. Standard Azure App service plan allows up to 10 instance (10 same website or 10 different website) to be hosted in Azure App Service plan. So based on this I understand that if user runs one web app or 10 web app the cost will be the same. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cost is based on the plan type, instance type, and number of instances. The number of deployed applications using the plan does not affect the plan cost.

You will pay for the number of instances running in your app plan, which may be less than the max.

Comment: So if App Service plan says it can scale out to 10 instance max in Standard plan you pay the same whether you run 1 or 10 instance?

Comment: No, would pay per-second, per-host. The cost per second increases as your app service scales up to more instances.

Comment: OK. So one can deploy any number of apps in a plan but they always deployed on all instances. They all share the same compute, store, cpu based on plan.. Every new instance  one scale out (up to max allowed) will have all the apps in it. But the charge in based on plan type, instance type and number of instances.

Comment: @Andy - yes, you've got it!